# How to manage user information with an external user database?

Tags: oauth2, openid

I'm developing an app suite that uses an OpenID Connect provider. But I guess my question works in all situations where there is a separate user info provider.
I persist which users create a given object in my db and I want to show to other users what the user name is. At the moment, I store the user name at this moment, but the user can change his name in the future. How do you manage this ?

Do you "duplicate" the user database to make sure that the name is always up to date ?
Do you use create WS to query each time ? (seems overblown to me)

I expected many people to have the same problem but I can't find any help.

Answer (score 1):

With current times, it's often the case that applications accept many different forms of authentication/identity be it social, OpenID, or internally created accounts. I think the solution most take (including myself) is to store identity data within the application in a database.

When the user first registers, you can query the identity service (OpenID) to get the user's name, email, profile picture, etc. then you store this data in your applications database. This allows you to maintain referential integrity through your database. It also means you don't have to juggle access tokens and try to keep them from expiring.

To keep the data up to date you have a couple options. You can either give the user the ability to change the data that you've stored (which will probably be required if you implement internal accounts in the application). If they change their name in OpenID, they would also have to change it in your system.

Or if you don't allow the user to change this information manually, you can refresh the data from the identity service each time the user logs into the system.